# WP: If Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I made a 2 language site in WordPress and I need to say that:

if html direction is RTL use some code else use another code...

I've tried this with the traditional way that I use in Joomla

```
<?php    if( $this->direction=="rtl"){ ?>
```

/images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Slider 01" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Slider 02" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Slider 03" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/04.jpg" alt="Slider 04" title="#htmlcaption" />  


       **هذا** مثال لما يمكن ان يكتب هنا. 
    

              


        /images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Slider 01" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Slider 02" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Slider 03" title="#htmlcaption" />   /images/slider/04.jpg" alt="Slider 04" title="#htmlcaption" />  
         PROVIDING COST-EFFECTIVE   AND RELIABLE MARINE TRANSPORTATIONS   
       **This** is an example of a HTML caption with a link. 
       **This** is an example of a HTML caption with a link. 
       **This** is an example of a HTML caption with a link.

But it always says there a fatal error.. I think I need to define `$this` as html page
but how to say that in PHP?

: Using $this when not in object context in C:\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wp\index.php on line 7

Comment: What fatal error? and what is in `// some code`?

Comment: What @MichaelBerkowski said as well as explaining to us which line this happens on, and what code is on this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it us built into another function called "language_attributes()".  Try this:

```
// if ( function_exists( 'is_rtl' ) ) # You may need to utilize this if is_rtl() is not defined
if( is_rtl() == 'rtl' ){
    // DO RTL code
}else{
    // DO LTR code    
}
```

Based on the following information:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/general-template.php#L0

http://wpml.org/2011/06/creating-right-to-left-rtl-wordpress-sites/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$script_name=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

Comment: this editor exclude my code ...my code is some html lines